# Saving a image which is captured by a camera on local machine on a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, camera

I am using HTML5 inputs to take a picture from camera using below line,

```
<input id="cameraInput" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"></input>
```

and getting used image in blob:, using following javascript,

```
var mobileCameraImage = function() {
    var that = this
        ;
      $("#cameraInput").on("change", that.sendMobileImage);
      if (!("url" in window) && ("webkitURL" in window)) {
        window.URL = window.webkitURL;
      }
});

var sendMobileImage = function( event ) {
    var that = this;
      if (event.target.files.length == 1 && event.target.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
          var capturedImage = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
              ;

          alert( capturedImage );
      }
});
```

Here, I am getting proper image url but the problem i am facing is to send this image url to the server, After reading blogs i found i can not send Blob: url to the server due to its local instance. Does anyone can help to save the clicked image on local machine on a folder or any where, or to help how i can send this image url to the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you really want to send *the image*  to the server, not an objectURL ?

Comment: I am trying to save image and then after want to send image url, so server can perform some task.

Comment: But you can't send an objectURL to the server and access that image serverside, that URL only exists in the browser, you have to send **the entire image** to the server to perform anything on it, and then send it back to the client again.

Comment: Is it possible to upload the captured image over aws s3hub and try to access the image url?

Comment: You're not quite getting it, read the documentation on createObjectURL -> *"The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created"*, the URL is just a fake URL that lets you access the image in the **browser**, you can't send that URL anywhere else and access the image, it can't be done, you have to send **the entire image** to your server, to AWS S3, or wherever you want it, but you **can not** send the URL, it's just a fake pointer to the resource.

Comment: Are you trying to process the images frame-by-frame on the server side? If so, there are other options for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to submit your form every time via [Ajax](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) or you may upload the image data manually. In order to do that, you may draw the image unto a canvas, then obtain the canvas data.

```
// create an image to receive the data
var img = $('<img>');

// create a canvas to receive the image URL
var canvas = $('<canvas>');
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

$("#cameraInput").on("change", function () {
  var capturedImage = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

  img.attr('src', capturedImage);
  ctx.drawImage(img);

  var imageData = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");

  // do something with the image data    
});
```

Or use a [`FileReader`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/FileReader.html)

```
// only need to create this once
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
  var imageData = reader.result;

  // do something with the image data
};

$("#cameraInput").on("change", function () {
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

Then you can upload that data to the server.

Comment: Why would the OP need to do that, he already has the image and doesn't say anything about needing a Base 64 string ?

Comment: I am sharing this as I had to code something similar for our user avatar software, where I needed to be able to crop the image before sending it to the server. For that, I used [Jcrop](http://jcrop.org/) and this allowed me to send other data along with it (i.e. the user info) and access the image data locally for manipulation. I thought that's what the OP asked for.